# How do I insert a limited number records to TableA from TableB , where TableC contains the list of records to insert?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6

Note:

```
TableA is Active_Orders
TableB is Old_Orders
TableC is Move_Orders
```

The field "contract" is unique in all three tables.

Here is what I got so far

Database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Active_Orders (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
contract VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO Active_Orders(name, contract)
VALUES ('steve', '3454'),
       ('tom', '6756'),
       ('becky', '9809');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Old_Orders (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
contract VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO Old_Orders(name,contract)
VALUES ('mark', '9896'),
       ('kelly', '0897'),
       ('paul', '1537'),
       ('will', '8254');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Move_Orders (
contract VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO Move_Orders(contract)
VALUES ('0897'),
       ('1537);
```

The Code I am using is:

```
INSERT INTO Active_Orders (name, contract)  
SELECT name, contract
FROM Old_Orders
WHERE Move_Orders.contract = Old_Orders.contract;
```

But I am getting

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'Move_Orders.contract' in 'where clause'
```

What I want the result to be is:

```
SELECT * FROM Active_Orders;

id  name    contract
1   steve   3454
2   tom     6756
3   becky   9809
4   kelly   0897
5   paul    1537
```

I understand that 'Move_Orders.contract' is not in the FROM clause so I am getting error, but I am not sure how to rewrite the statement to get the output I need.

Comment: *But I am getting* Of course - this table is not mentioned in `FROM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Active_Orders (name, contract)  
SELECT Old_Orders.name, Old_Orders.contract
FROM Old_Orders
JOIN Move_Orders ON Move_Orders.contract = Old_Orders.contract;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Active_Orders (name, contract)  
SELECT Old_Orders.name, Old_Orders.contract
FROM Old_Orders, Move_Orders 
WHERE Move_Orders.contract = Old_Orders.contract;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Active_Orders (name, contract)  
SELECT name, contract
FROM Old_Orders
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT contract 
               FROM Move_Orders
               WHERE Move_Orders.contract = Old_Orders.contract )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly a literal translation from English:

```
INSERT INTO Active_Orders (name, contract)  
SELECT o.name, o.contract
FROM Old_Orders o
WHERE o.contract IN (SELECT contract FROM Move_Orders)
```

You could also do a INNER JOIN between old_orders and move_orders, which will cause moveorders to filter the list of oldorders down to just those also present in  move_orders

```
INSERT INTO Active_Orders (name, contract)  
SELECT o.name, o.contract
FROM 
  Old_Orders o
  INNER JOIN Move_Orders m ON o.contract = m.contract
```